# How to invoke / trigger different multiple AWS Step Functions at a time , using a single AWS Lambda Function written in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-step-functions

please observe the below AWS Lambda function ( in python code) to invoke a single AWS Step Function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

print("stating to invoke the AWS Step function.")

response = {"code":400, "message":""}

try :
     stepFunction = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
     response = stepFunction.start_execution(
            stateMachineARN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
             )
except Exception as e:
      response["message"] = f"failed to invoke the step function,{e}"

finally:
      print(response)
      return response
```

Now, I want to invoke different multiple AWS Step functions at a time ( in series and in parallel ) using the above single AWS Lambda function. Could anyone help me on how to modify the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics, but be careful you don't accidentally call this function back in another lambda function or you'll get into a perpetual loop

```
def trigger_my_other_lambda(event, context):
    invoked_function_name = os.environ['INVOKED_FUNCTION_NAME']

    # this lambda function invokes another lambda function
    # invoke other lambda as many times as in tasks_list or other range
    for myarn in arnslist:
        '''pass data in form of dictionary; this shows up and must be parsed by the event argument of receiving lambda'''
        data = {"stateMachineARN" : myarn}
        # print(data)
        response = client.invoke(
            FunctionName=invoked_function_name,
            # InvocationType='RequestResponse', # synchornous - waits for response
            InvocationType='Event', # asynch - much faster - doesn't wait for response
            Payload=json.dumps(data)
        )
```

Then your existing lambda would use the event like this:

```
 stepFunction = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
 response = stepFunction.start_execution(
        stateMachineARN = event['stateMachineARN']
         )
```